# pip install error for pyzmail on mac (10.15.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I'm getting an error when installing "pyzmail" for Python on Mac OS (v10.15.5). See error code at bottom. I've attempted to load pyzmail as I do any other module via the Terminal using pip (currently running v19.2.3). I have had no issues installing 8 or so other modules (pyperclip, nltk etc). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The exact syntax that throws this error is as follows:

```
pip3 install pyzmail


 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4m/pjsf6l4s5n35mzvfwfmplf5h0000gn/T/pip-install-vxmcvxlo/distribute/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4m/pjsf6l4s5n35mzvfwfmplf5h0000gn/T/pip-install-vxmcvxlo/distribute/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/4m/pjsf6l4s5n35mzvfwfmplf5h0000gn/T/pip-install-vxmcvxlo/distribute/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/4m/pjsf6l4s5n35mzvfwfmplf5h0000gn/T/pip-install-vxmcvxlo/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "/private/var/folders/4m/pjsf6l4s5n35mzvfwfmplf5h0000gn/T/pip-install-vxmcvxlo/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "/private/var/folders/4m/pjsf6l4s5n35mzvfwfmplf5h0000gn/T/pip-install-vxmcvxlo/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.command.install import install
      File "/private/var/folders/4m/pjsf6l4s5n35mzvfwfmplf5h0000gn/T/pip-install-vxmcvxlo/distribute/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from setuptools.command import install_scripts
      File "/private/var/folders/4m/pjsf6l4s5n35mzvfwfmplf5h0000gn/T/pip-install-vxmcvxlo/distribute/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
      File "/private/var/folders/4m/pjsf6l4s5n35mzvfwfmplf5h0000gn/T/pip-install-vxmcvxlo/distribute/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27importlib._bootstrap%27+has+no+attribute+%27SourceFileLoader%27

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will solve your problem: **easy_install pyzmail**

Please let me know if you have any issues.